# WPF application in a loop, how to not have the whole application freeze?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I am having fun with WPF and got a problem. I have googled and found this [website](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/878ea631-c76e-49e8-9e25-81e76a3c4fe3/) that has the same problem of me but without any working solution.

The problem is that I have a button that do some processing of data (around 30 sec). I want to have the button to disable and to have log writing in a text box... the problem is that it doesn't disable and it doesn't wrote any thing on the textbox until the processing is completely done.

Any idea?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        this.button1.IsEnabled = false;
        //Long stuff here
         txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Blabla");
        //End long stuff here
        this.button1.IsEnabled = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have said, use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or some other method of doing work asychronously.

You can declare it under your `Window`, initialize it somewhere like the `Loaded` event, and use it in the `Click` event.  Here's your method, modified to use `BackgroundWorker`, assuming you've declared it under the `Window` as `_bw`:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    _bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((o, args) =>
    {
        //Long stuff here       
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Blabla")));
    });

    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((o, args) =>
    {
        //End long stuff here
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => this.button1.IsEnabled = true));
    });
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.IsEnabled = false;

    _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Note that anything that modifies your UI from another thread must be done within a [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) or [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) call, WPF does not allow you to get or set `DependencyProperty` values from any thread but the one where the object was created (more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.checkaccess.aspx)).

If you wanted to read from `txtLog` instead of modifying it, the code would be the same:

```
//Long stuff here       
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => 
{
    string myLogText = txtLog.Text;
    myLogText = myLogText + Environment.NewLine + "Blabla";
    txtLog.Text = myLogText;
}));
```

Comment: This is more what I have read yet on other website. Thx! Do you have a snippet to READ data... usually with 2.0 I do not need to do something but I have a cross thread exception while reading the textbox value :S

Comment: Yes, getting or setting dependency properties must be done on the UI thread, so it has to be within a Dispatcher.Invoke call as above.

Answer (score 3):

do it async. create a backgroundworker process to handle the data and the application will continue to respond. [MSDN Resources on the Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Since WPF is using C# (or VB.net) you can still use the same types of threading objects. I've used the background worker successfully in a WPF app myself.

Comment: Alright, like in normal C#. I thought it would have been something special with WPF:P

Comment: just create an instance of the class directly, instead of the toolbox

Answer (score 3):

That operation is being performed on the UI thread.  This means that it will block the Windows message pump from processing until it has completed.  no pump = no UI updates.  You should launch the job on another thread.  I don't know WPF, but in C# I would use either the Thread or [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) classes.

Comment: It doesn't work the same way, I am readying and you cannot use this.BeginInvoke... your answer is not complete sorry cannot accept.

Comment: Well, the name is different, but the concept is the same.  I said I did not know WPF.  It's ok that you didn't accept, the accepted answer is far more complete.