# Label changed in while loop does not update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, loops

When running this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            DateTime dtCurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
            label1.Content = dtCurrentTime.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }

}
}
```

to update the label frequently, the window never opens. But when I remove the while loop it works but it just doesn't update the label... So how would I update the label to show the current time without any user input?
Thanks,
L

Comment: You're probably never allowing the thread to redraw.  Maybe use a timer to update the label every second?

Comment: sounds like a job for `Timer` you also appear to be in an infinite loop while what is true is another question when do you set what every you are checking to be true to false..?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651857/wpf-application-in-a-loop-how-to-not-have-the-whole-application-freeze , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457539/wpf-gui-stops-responding-as-some-functions-are-called-in-loop?rq=1 etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're blocking your UI thread.

You can't run code in a loop this way on the UI thread.  You need to setup a `Timer`, and update your label in the timer, to allow the UI thread to continue executing and process messages.

This can look like:

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();


        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer 
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
            };
        timer.Tick += (o,e) =>
            {
                DateTime dtCurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
                label1.Content = dtCurrentTime.ToLongTimeString();
            };
        timer.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

This will cause the timer to update the UI two times per second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/):

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
              .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
              .Subscribe(x => Label.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

You probably don't want to add the dependency just for this though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you are blocking the main Thread, use a Timer like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Timer timer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -5):

You could try a `do...while` loop to accomplish the same, this will run the code once (the `do` part) and then continue to execute for the `while` condition.

Comment: `-1`.  `while (true)` is no different than `do...while(true)`.  Both create infinite loops.